# Error while running Cordova project to Windows device?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-cli, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm a beginner developer for Cordova apps (Hybrid Application project)
Currently the following platforms are listed using this commandline window:
[image]
cordova platform -l
Installed platforms:

Available platforms:
  amazon-fireos ~3.6.3 (deprecated)
  android ~6.1.1
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0
  browser ~4.1.0
  firefoxos ~3.6.3
  webos ~3.7.0
  windows ~4.4.0
  wp8 ~3.8.2 (deprecated)
Now, I added `cordova platform add android` and `cordova platform add windows` so it's installed and necessary folders for respective platforms exist.

I am using Eclipse and installed the THYM plugin to build Hybrid Mobile Applications so now when [image] so here import project and now all set.

Now I right click on project and select the option to `Run as Windows Emulator` and it asked me to install Windows SDK. How can I do that?

And can you help me by showing how to run it on iOS and Windows? iOS is not listed in the platform list so what is the alternative to use it. I even tried PhoneGap build to generate builds for iOS which asked me to add certificate.  The windows options are not at all able to view. Please see the attached image:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try installing Visual Studio 2015/2017.

Comment: No, using Windows Eclipse how to do it ?

Comment: I mean that its an easy way to install Windows SDK. See also http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/platforms/win8/index.html#requirements-and-support

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen on the first screenshot, there are no installed platforms, only available ones. Start with `cordova platform add android`

Comment: sorry i have installed windows and android already,it's not been listed in screenshot.